# Disconnected subspace

Tags: general-topology

We know that if $X$ is a disconnected topological space and $C$ is a connected component of $X$, then $C$ is closed. Besides, if $X$ is locally connected, then $C$ is open and closed. Now suppose $Y\subset X$ is a disconnected (topological) subspace of $X$. The proof of the above results suggest that each connected component $C$ of $Y$ *is closed in* $X$ (not only in $Y$), and if $X$ is locally connected, then $C$ *is open in* $ X$ (not only open in $Y$). Am I right?

Comment: If $X=[0,1], Y=X\setminus \{\frac1  2\}$ the components of $Y$ are not closed in $X$.